# JS: Display specific table rows if a specific value is in that row

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i am trying [here](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) to display only certain rows when a checkbox is cheked.

For example only the rows that containt the 2.5 as a value if the checkbox 2.5 is cheked.

**I can't edit the HTML code of the table** and i tried something like this withour results:

JS

```
$('input[name="rooms_check"]').change(function(){
$('input[name="rooms_check"]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('tr td:nth-child(2):contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').hide();
    } else {
        $('tr td:nth-child(2):contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').show();
    }
});
});
```

HTML: (I can only edit the `<input>` HTML)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="2.5">
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="3.5">
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="4.5">
```

Any tip?

PS: I am using Wordpress.

Comment: You should mention in the tags of this post that it is about wordpress, because it strongly limits the possible answers to your question.

Comment: I just edited the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$('input[name="rooms_check"]').change(
  function (){
    // a checkbox is clicked > display affected rows
    if(0<$('input[name="rooms_check"]:checked').length){
      // hide all rowsin body
      $('#tablepress-5 tbody tr').css('display', 'none');

      // display the rows with the correct values
      $('input[name="rooms_check"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $('#tablepress-5 td:nth-child(2):contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').parent().css('display', 'table-row');
        }
      });
    }
    // no checkboxes clicked > display all rows
    else{
      $('#tablepress-5 tbody tr').css('display', 'table-row');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5kt3fegy/
- ignore the onclick="changeRows()" in the fiddle-example in the html part - it is a code-rest of a test that i forgot to remove... ;-)

**Note:** I have also added the case "no checkbox activated"